# Where are the MySQL InnoDB log files stored?

Tags: mysql, log

I changed some settings for my InnoDB tables in MySQL and encountered [the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6975938/641514) that InnoDB was not shown in `SHOW ENGINES` output. As an answer I got [the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975938/fine-tuning-of-my-cnf-for-innodb-tables-fails-with-setting-of-innodb-log-file-s/6976088#6976088) to delete the log files of InnoDB. Where are these stored on Ubuntu?

Comment: `ls /var/lib/mysql/` did the job. Every file `ib_logfile0`, `iblogfile1` is a InnoDB logfile, if I am not mistaken, that is. :-)

Comment: You are correct, those are the innodb log files.

Comment: Aufwind, you should make your comment an answer and make this question "answered"

Comment: @SpamapS: Done! :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ls /var/lib/mysql/` did the job. Every file `ib_logfile0`, `iblogfile1` is a InnoDB logfile, if I am not mistaken, that is. :-)